# Reading a xml file from Sdcard not works

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I am trying to read a xml  file from sdcard but it not works .Blank activity is loaded and the TextView is empty. if i remove the code to read xml and just set text as t.setText("hello"); it works fine

the code is here.

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


     setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdcard1);


     TextView t;


     t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.T1);


     try{


          File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/page1.xml");


          InputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);


          // InputStreamReader input= new InputStreamReader(fileIS);


          xpp.setInput(fileIS,"UTF-8");


          eventType = xpp.getEventType();


          while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){


             if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                          t.setText(t.getText()+xpp.getText());
                  }
         }


       } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {


            e1.printStackTrace();


       } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {


        // TODO Auto-generated catch block


        e.printStackTrace()
       }

    }
```

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page1>

<Text1>Hello.</Text1>

<Text2>World!</Text2>

</page1>

and the xml file in sdcard/page1.xml
I have tried with different ways but not works . 
thanks ...

I found now i have to write two lines of code inside while loop

```
    eventType = xpp.next();


    eventType = xpp.getEventType();
```

Now it works Fine ! Thanks for help....

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?  What problem do you have?  What is your question?

Comment: I have read a text file from sd card and displayed sucessfully in the above TextView t; But readind from page1.xml through pullparser gives a blank page . that means the TextView t is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code -

File rootDir = null;

            rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            try {
                File myFile = new File(rootDir.getAbsolutePath(), "Your file Name");
                FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);


            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: Please do not just post answers with code.  How does this answer the question.  Why is it better than the OP code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file using below code:

> ```
>      File myFile = new File("/sdcard/page1.xml");
>         FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
>         BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
>                 new InputStreamReader(fIn));
>         String aDataRow = "";
>         String aBuffer = "";
>         while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
>             aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
>             Log.d("File Is DATA:===>",aBuffer.toString());
>         }
>         myReader.close();
>         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
>                 "Done reading SD 'page1.xml'",
>                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
>                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please do not just post answers with code.  How does this answer the question.  Why is it better than the OP code?